# Forbidden 403 error when trying to access site via Instagram

Tags: ios, instagram, http-status-code-403

When (most) people using iPhones or iPads try to access my website via Instagram, they get a Forbidden 403 error. More specifically, it says: "You don't have permission to access on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." My instagram handle is @bodyandsoulsustenance. It seems to work fine via instagram.com/bodyandsoulsustenance, however. Iphones and iPads (I was told) seem to be the problem.

I've updated all of my plugins and Wordpress software, and scanned my site for any malware. My host, a2hosting, told me to contact a developer for help. I asked one at Codeable but he was unable to figure it out. Please help! Thank you.

Update: Fixed by deleting and redownloading the Instagram app.

Comment: A2 experience malware issue, right? It will better for you to backup your file and migrate to other providers. It seems that until now, they are still struggling with their issue.

Comment: Thanks, but this actually started before that occurred. I also haven't noticed any changes in relation to the malware issue, personally.

Comment: Hmm... Weird... Basically it is caused by your plugins. Please just test to uninstall your plugin, then reinstall it back. Then, you can find which plugin cause the issue. As I know that A2 experience big issue with their windows server. Maybe you are using their Linux server. Just make sure you have backup on your end.

Comment: Thanks, it is weird, because I've tried disabling all of my plugins multiple times but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Are you using their windows or linux server? have you try to contact their support? Basically it is caused by plugins that you installed. Make sure that you keep update your plugins. Your plugins can become your security hole. Maybe you can read this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-identify-that-your-wordpress-site-is-hacked.